# how to select product[prod_name] in rails action as params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an HTML element in a form with name `product[prod_name]`

how do get access to its value in my action using `params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value like this:

```
params[:product][:prod_name]
```